# How do I specify a url in express other than my main?

Tags: node.js, express

I want to be able to access my http://localhost:3000/ and get back hello world, but when I go to http://localhost:3000/public I would like to serve different content.

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use('/', function (req, res) {
  var data = '<h1>hello world</h1>';

  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  res.end(data)
});

app.get('/public', function (req, res) {
  var data = '<h1>welcome to public</h1>';

  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  res.end(data)
});


app.listen(port);

console.log('server started at port %s ', port);
```

This is my code but it doesn't react to /public when I run it.
Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here? Thanks for reading :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Express confusing with route(single / Considering both as same route).

Try for this:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    port = process.env.PORT || 3010;



app.get('/public', function (req, res) {
console.log("Inside public");
  var data = '<h1>welcome to public</h1>';

  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  res.end(data)
});

app.use('/', function (req, res) {
  var data = '<h1>hello world</h1>';

  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  res.end(data)
});

app.listen(port);
```

Comment: I will, I just had to wait 3 Minutes for some reason :)